# How to pass binary file through json in java?

Tags: java, httpwebrequest

There is a scenario where I need to pass the binary file in the request body for the post method- HttpWebclient using java code

Comment: welcome to SO. let us know what you have tried

Comment: I have tried passing the request body {"file":encryptedmessage} in the post method but still, it's giving error

Comment: What are they expecting as value of file JSON field? An URL? A String? If you can control both side of the service and the client you can use base64 encode/decode.